# Anaconda fedora install: conda: command not found

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, fedora

I've installed Anaconda and have added the environment variable export `PATH="~/anaconda/bin:$PATH"` to my .zshrc but still can't run any 'conda' commands in my terminal. I have followed these commands([source](https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-python-on-ubuntu-anaconda-65623042cb5a)) to install anaconda.

```
# Go to home directory
cd ~

# You can change what anaconda version you want at 
# https://repo.continuum.io/archive/
wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
zsh Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p ~/anaconda
rm Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
echo 'export PATH="~/anaconda/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc 

# Refresh basically
source ~/.zshrc
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issue often arise due to incorrect paths to your Python distribution. Basically, your computer does not know where to look for the correct file or program and you need to tell it where to look using your system's $PATH variable. You will thus need to manually set the paths by editing your `.profile` or `.rc` file. The most commonly used shell is bash. Both Anaconda and Canopy assume you're running the `Bash` shell and will put the path to your install there.

The steps below worked for me on Mac, it should work on Linux as well:

1. Go to your home directory by typing `cd ~` from the prompt, or by open that same directory in Finder.

2. Now get a list of all the files in this folder, including the hidden ones:

```
ls -la
```

or, directly in Finder (without the "+"):

```
CMD + SHIFT + .
```

Now, you probably have (a) *both* the `.profile` and `.bash_profile`, or (b) *just one* of them, or (c) *none* of them:

3.**a** If you are using Bash, you're looking for files called `.profile` and `.bash_profile`. Which you have will depend on your system configuration. If you have both, this is probably the root cause of your problem; `.bash_profile` overrides `.profile` if both are present. In this case, open `.profile` and copy everything you find inside across to `.bash_profile`.

3.**b** If you only have one of `.bash_profile` or `.profile`, open it in an editor and have a look. You're looking for any obvious references to Python or your distribution (Anaconda, Canopy) on any of the uncommented-out lines. You'll probably see several lines that look something like:

```
PATH="Users/<your user name>/Library/...:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

In the rare case that you don't see any reference to Anaconda at all, you will need to add the lines yourself. Add, for example, the following to the file:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

3.**c** If it turns out that you don't have any of the files, you would have to create one by yourself. Do this by entering `touch .bash_profile` in the prompt, or, simply right click and create a new file directly in Finder. Add the following to the file (same as in (b)):

```
export PATH=~/anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

4. Save the file. Quit and restart any program that use Python (including the Terminal window), and you should be good to go.

More detailed info here (including for Windows):

https://github.com/landlab/landlab/wiki/Correcting-Install-Paths

Comment: Please don't post links as answer, but explain content rather. What if the link isn't available anymore and someone is looking for help about the same topic?